# Connect tableau to Google Dataproc

Tags: tableau-api, google-cloud-dataproc

I am wondering how to connect tableau to Google Dataproc via SPARK SQL?

I am trying to connect using External IP address of the master node and port but it does not work.

Comment: Which port and are the Dataproc cluster and Tableau server on the same GCE network?

Answer (score 0):

The following may be useful, it is specific to Hortonworks but the concepts should be the same:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/5469/working-with-firewalled-hdp-via-ssh-tunnel-and-soc.html

I assume Tableau is not hosted on GCE?